# Row grouping with AG-Grid viewport model

Tags: ag-grid

The documentation says I need to implement my own groupCellRenderer in order to achieve row grouping with viewport model. Is there any example of such implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There is one in the Ag-Grid documentation page, section 'Example Group cellRenderer':

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

Comment: As far as I can tell, this documentation only shows how to customise the display of the value, but not how expand/collapse works, which is required for viewport.